# Consume Secure Web Service in MVC3

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

I've consumed web services before (add reference > advanced > web reference). However, this one is proving difficult as I need to authenticate first.

I have the address to my wsdl file that someone in our IS department made available. I need to authenticate with my network username/pass to use it, according to his instructions.

So, using small words ;), can anyone help me understand how I might add this webservice to make calls?

I am using VS 10 MVC3 (razor). The wsdl is accessed over http - https is not available.

I appreciate all help!

### Update

Based on @john-saunders post I took a local copy of the WSDL and referenced it (not as a web reference). I now see the  added to my web.config and it would seem to take username/password... but again, I'm new here. I really appreciate any help in pushing me over this (I hope) final hump!

### Update #2

I've put in the following code. But intellisense doesn't show methods, I know there is search capability where I can pass one value (emplID) and get back other values (name, birth date). How do I call these/test my authentication?

```
using (var hrData = new CHMC_HRTECH_RES())
{
    //CHMC_HRTECH_RES hrData = new CHMC_HRTECH_RES();
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add(new Uri(hrData.Url),
    "Negotiate",
    new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass"));
    hrData.Credentials = cache;
}
```

Comment: Does the web service use Integrated Windows Authentication (NTLM)? Or some other authentication scheme? Which?

Comment: You shouldn't use "Add Web Reference". Just use "Add Service Reference".

Comment: How do I tell what authentication scheme? I was anticipating I would have to pass a username/password to it in the request/connection string. This is all new to me, but would that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't access the WSDL by URL, then ask the owners of the service to email you the WSDL and any other files it includes. Save those to disk and pass the file path to "Add Service Reference".

Comment: Interesting - He did email me the WSDL but I wasn't sure what I might need to do from there. Would I save it to my bin folder and reference it?  How does authentication work if I do this locally?

Comment: The WSDL is just a file. The fact that you can get it through a URL should not be strange -  you can get most files through a URL these days. Just use "Add Service Reference" and specify the path to the WSDL file on disk. Don't put it in the bin folder, though. That folder is meant to be cleaned out on each build.

Comment: Thanks - I did that. I have an entry in web.config... but I'm still unsure how to use the web service. It seems I need to provide the username/pass in code, but I've not found a working sample yet. Do I need to do this?